# How can I exit my Dart (vm) program?

Tags: exit, dart, error-code

(Sorry, I know that is this is mostly a repeat of John Evan's question, but the previous answer must now be outdated.)

I'd like to be able to specify an `exitCode` and leave the my (vm) program if a certain condition occurs (for debugging purposes only).

Note from the above I cannot `import 'dart:builtin'`, and I can't find mention of `exit()` in this context in the API.

(My more detailed situation is that my work involves rather massive detailed output and as I test and debug things I have found it most convenient to just `exit();` the program - clearly only appropriate during development.)

Thanks,

_g

Comment: Good catch.  I'll go back and edit the older answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further searching has shown that the required support is now in the 'io' library so this is working for me:

(Nothing specific to an error code is getting printed out at the console, but that's ok.)

```dart
import('dart:io');

main() {
    print("just before the exit command...");
    exit(99);
    print("We should not see this")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`exit()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_io.html#exit):

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  exit(0); // Standard out code, 0 = no errors.
}
```